# XSL transformation, output as text

Tags: xml, xslt

```
Sample XSLT:

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="main">
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
SSN: <xsl:value-of select="ssn"/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="address1"/>
DOB: <xsl:value-of select="dob"/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="address2"/>
GENDER: <xsl:value-of select="gender"/>
EYE COLOR: <xsl:value-of select="eye"/>
HEIGHT: <xsl:value-of select="height"/>
HAIR COLOR: <xsl:value-of select="hair"/>
WEIGHT: <xsl:value-of select="weight"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


Sample XML:

    <main>
<name>CHTP CLS DEBY</name>
<dob>1999-01-08</dob>
<ssn>18454512</ssn>
<address1>115 Z 88TH UL #226-F</address1>
<address2>ARVADA, CO 80004</address2>
<gender>M</gender>
<eye>Blue</eye>
<hair>Brown</hair>
<height>182</height>
<weight>69</weight>
</main>
```

I want to achieve something like this,

```
CHTP CLS DEBY                              SSN: *****4512
115 Z 88TH UL #226-F                                 DOB: 1999-01-08
ARVADA, CO 80004                        

Gender:         M
Eye Color:      Blue                                   Height: 182        
Hair Color:     Brown                                  Weight: 69
```

Using XSL transformation.

Comment: And what does your **input** look like? [What have **you** tried so far?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) See [Jon Skeet's SO question checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) - have you done all of this already??

Comment: Input is XML file.I am able to pick up information from XML but not able to show it in the above mentioned manner.

Comment: P.S The tab separated part...I am not sure about that.is there any function in xsl that allows you to do so?

Comment: @avinashchavan, to make a question a good one .. you need to provide input XML, (a sample not the realtime) also what have you tried.. It is a good practice,

Comment: @avinashchavan, here in your question .. we don't know what your XML really looks like! from where DOB is coming? where Gender is coming from? you need to elaborate and yet keep the question simpler and understandable!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a general equivalent of `printf("%-30s", something)` in XSLT 1.0, the usual trick I use is to create a variable containing a long string of spaces and then take substrings of the appropriate length.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="spaces"
    select="'                                                                   '"/>

  <xsl:template match="main">
    <xsl:call-template name="print-padded">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="name" />
      <xsl:with-param name="width" select="43" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>SSN: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ssn" />
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:call-template name="print-padded">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="address1" />
      <xsl:with-param name="width" select="53" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>DOB: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="dob" />
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>

    <!-- and so on for the other elements -->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="print-padded">
    <xsl:param name="str" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="width" select="0" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$str" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($spaces, 1, $width - string-length($str))" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I prefer to use character references for the newlines, as that is more robust to (accidental or deliberate) reformatting of the `.xsl` file.

Edit: I notice you're also trying to obfuscate the SSN, you can use the same trick for that

```
<xsl:variable name="stars" select="'*******************'" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring($stars, 1, string-length(ssn) - 4)" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring(ssn, string-length(ssn) - 4)" />
```

Comment: @
InfantProgrammer'Aravind' am able to generate the output in text format, but i am not able to execute the formatting (i.e fixed interval tab separated text) part.

Comment: Please check.i've updated the question.

Comment: Comeon!!!I've updated my question. Please reopen it!

Comment: @avinashchavan I have voted to reopen, but it takes votes from several different people before this actually happens.

Comment: not a problem mate.Thanks for the help!!!